# Laravel 5 Class not Found, using namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a custom class I added to Classes, `invoice.php` within the Classes folder (`\App\Classes`).

When using a controller function, I can't execute a static function, says Class not found. I have the namespace and use set up like any other classes, similar to `Helpers.php`.

Class:

```
<?php namespace App\Classes;

class invoice {
//
}
?>
```

Contoller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Classes\invoice;

class CustomerController extends Controller {
//
}
?>
```

Error:

```
FatalErrorException in CustomerController.php line 284:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\invoice' not found
```

I've been stuck here for two hours and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Composer is using psr-4 and the Helpers.php file works fine, but my custom class file doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: the "i" in invoice is lowercase on your class name. Should be uppercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow PSR-4 you need to have your class names initial-caps. The "i" should be capitalized here:

```
<?php namespace App\Classes;

class Invoice {
   //
}
```

Also fix your `use` as well. Then when `Invoice` is used in your controller, it will pick up the correct namespace to use for resolving that class. What's happening currently is it is not finding a matching reference in your `use` section, so it assumes it is in the same namespace of the controller class that calls it.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but my class name is in upper-camel-case. I have a class `class InvoiceGenerator` in `app/Classes/InvoiceGenerator` folder. And in my controller, I am using `use App\Classes\InvoiceGenerator\InvoiceGenerator;` Any idea?